# Chat room “info” pages' titles are not distinct

Tags: bug, chat

If I click on the “info” link for a chat room, the resulting page's title is always “Overview | chat.stackexchange.com” (or “Overview | chat.stackoverflow.com”). The title should include the name of the chat room.